# Why variance in kalman?

Tags: normal-distribution, kalman-filter

1. What is the intuition/explanation of using variances in kalman filters?
2. Also confusion in joint PDF considered in kalman filter. For eg, when we take a 1D kinematics, say position and velocity of a moving object in x direction, widely used example for kalman filters, both $\displaystyle {{{x}_{t}}}$ and $\displaystyle {{{{\dot{x}}}_{t}}}$ are dependent (velocity is derived from displacement over time). So if at all we take joint PDF we should introduce baysian. That is to take  PDFs  f($\displaystyle {{{x}_{t}}}$) and f($ \displaystyle {{{{\dot{x}}}_{t}}|{{x}_{t}}}$), but we seem to just multiply PDFs f($\displaystyle {{{x}_{t}}}$) and f($ \displaystyle {{{{\dot{x}}}_{t}}}$) which am unable to comprehend. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Why (co-)variances?  Because no system, no model, and no measurement is perfect.  Every position measurement provides more evidence to prefer or reject various models and parameter values for those models.  However, no amount of evidence can absolutely select a "correct" model or "correct" parameters.  The filter is designed to partition deviations from predicted and observed measurement into the part that conforms with the model (i.e., is compatible with the predicted observables distribution from the prior time step) and the part that is "noise" (i.e., whatever disagreement with the prediction is observed).  Note that measurement noise, unconverged model parameters, unmodeled influences, and mismatch between model and system all contribute to the "noise".

You don't have independent (marginal) distributions of $x_t$ and $\dot{x}_t$.  You have a joint PDF of $(x_t, \dot{x}_t)$ pairs.  When you use this joint PDF to predict the distribution for the next time step, you introduce correlation (and covariance) because, for each choice of $x_t$, the image of that vertical slice of the PDF is angled -- the parts corresponding to larger $\dot{x}_t$ are shifted further to the right and those to lesser $\dot{x}_t$ are shifted further to the left.  At each prediction, the independent variances get mixed into the covariance.  This is illustrated and explained in different words (and with equations) at [[B]](http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/).  Also, at each new prediction, the effect of the likelihood of more extreme parts of the previous PDFs that are incompatible with the new observation are suppressed in the update.  (That is, if the observation keeps being a little to the right for several updates, both the left tail of the position and the "to the left" tail of the velocity are suppressed, tending to push the prediction to "catch up".)

It is not that $x_t$ and $\dot{x}_t$ are dependent -- they are not; one can easily imagine prior histories giving any pair of current positions and velocities.  (Note that specific models may implement a constraint causing a dependency, but your question doesn't indicate that you are thinking of model constraints.)  However, $x_{t+1}$ is strongly dependent on both $x_t$ and $\dot{x}_t$.  In addition $\dot{x}_{t+1}$ is weakly dependent on $\dot{x}_t$ since infinite acceleration is very expensive.  Since one has only a simultaneous distribution of $(x_t, \dot{x}_t)$ pairs, one pushes that distribution forward in time, subject to model constraints, to produce a prediction of the next state.  Then the system is observed and that new information is used to update the predicted distribution.  The Kalman filter does not bother to represent any possible joint distribution, it uses a simple join Gaussian, so only needs to track the mean and the covariance matrix.

[B] Babb, Tim, "How a Kalman filter works, in pictures", http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/ .

Comment: thank you very much for a detailed answer, but its difficult to visualize and comprehend it. I checked Babb's article. My vague understanding is  
1. It is understandable that they multiply 2 guassian, but the velocity PDF is velocity given position or just velocity's? is there any difference in them?

Comment: 2. I understand what variance is in rough sense, its a spread, but how its information gets transformed in K and then in new state estimation? when I multiply 2 probabilities I inherently visualize the scenario behind that multiplication, but here we multiply variance weight with probable previous step to get next new step?

Comment: The Kalman filter is always using a [joint PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution), in fact a [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) because the variables are neither assumed independent nor assumed conditionally dependent.  You keep speaking as if there are two PDFs.  There are not; there is one joint PDF.

Comment: Perhaps think of $K$ as the coefficient in a single-pole filter (if you have this background).  Alternatively, it is a running estimate of the significance of a discrepancy between the measurement and the prediction.  If $K$ is the identity, the new measurement replaces the prediction mean and the [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) (more about bivariate distributions and why covariance is necessary to completely describe them is there) clamps to zero (no uncertainty).  Otherwise, the components of $K$ specify how much to update the parts of the prediction.